# How can i rewrite/remove the first '%2F' from the parameter in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx

Hi I would like to rewrite the following url:

```
example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=%2Fitems%2Fxxx
```

to:

```
example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=items%2Fxxx
```

My config looks something like this, i just can't figure out the regex expression to remove the first '%2F'  from the parameter.

```
 location / {

  if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
      rewrite ^_escaped_fragment_=%2F ???? permanent;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the job for me:

```
if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=/(.+)") {
      set $key1 $1;
      rewrite ^ /?_escaped_fragment_=$key1? break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 location / {

  if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_=(.*)") {
      rewrite ^_escaped_fragment_=%2F(.*) example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working. i have tested the if block with `rewrite ^/.*\?  http://$server_name/test` and nginx redirects me to the test page. but with `^_escaped_fragment_=%2F(.*) http://$server_name/?_escaped_fragment_=$1 permanent;` nothing happends